# Question about using isogenies to mask elliptic pair

Tags: signature, isogeny

> For this question I'm referring to the ed25519 algorithm

In blockchain one project (Monero) shot itself in the foot a while back by having senders derive public keys from an ed25519 pair, by performing scalar multiplication of the random value against the '8' co-factor subgroup.

The issue here was that they were using a scheme which requires that there be no other valid derivations among other co-factor subgroups (i.e., '4' and '2').

This led to the construction of Ristretto, which is like an abstraction of the ed25519 coordinates to provide a prime order subgroup. The implementation I'm going by is the one where this Ristretto abstraction is built from the '4' co-factor subgroup of the ed25519 key pair in order to form a Jacobi quartic curve.

To my understanding, from that point - an isogeny between the Jacobi quartic and the ed25519 pair we used before (but this time creating a mapping with the '8' co-factor subgroup).

**My Questions**

Let's say that there's a 3rd-party somewhere that needs to verify the authenticity of a signature.

Also, let's say that this 3rd-party possesses knowledge of the jacobi quartic but **nothing else**. So they do not know what this was abstracted from.

Now let's say the original creator of the ed25519 key pair that the Jacobi quartic was created from provides:

1. Public key derived from the isogeny;
2. A valid signature constructed from the private key of that public key derived from the isogeny.

From here, I am curious:

1. Is it possible for this 3rd-party to determine whether the public key is the correctly derived isogeny?
2. If 'yes' to the question above, is it reasonable to assume that it would be impossible for the 3rd-party observer to have derived the ed25519 public key from the Jacobi quartic, correct?
3. How is the 'Jacobi quartic' represented notationally? Is it presented in the same way as a public key from other private / public key pairings derived from points on an algebraic curve of some sort?
4. Can one generate a signature from that Jacobi quartic curve that's formed? (via Ristretto's btw)
5. If yes to the question above, is it the same or different from the derived isogeny?
6. If the signature of the Jacobi quartic is different from its derived isogeny, is there any mathematical relationship between the two?
7. If the signature of the Jacobi quartic is different from its derived isogeny, could one somehow mathematically figure out what the isogeny signature is supposed to be if they knew the ed25519 pairing that the isogeny would be formed from as well as the message in question that needed to be signed?

Comment: 1. yes, the point validation 2. No, the coset has [4 elements](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/88209/18298), right? 3. Probably same, (not checked any code) 4. That is why Ristretto has been created, right?

Comment: Thank you! Any thought on the questions after 5?