# Convert sr25519 key pair to Curve25519 key pair

Tags: encryption, public-key, elliptic-curves, libsodium

I'm trying to implement public key encryption that support key pairs generated by different libraries:

- Curve25519 - libsodium `cryptoBoxKeypair()`
- Ed25519 - Google Tink `Ed25519Sign.KeyPair.newKeyPair()`
- sr25519 - Polkadot Schnorrkel over Ristretto

I'm using libsodium `cryptoBoxSealOpenEasy()` for encryption that is works, obviously, with Curve25519 and with Ed25519 after conversion with libsodium `convertKeyPairEd25519ToCurve25519()`. But I'm stuck with sr25519 - don't know how to convert it to Curve25519.

Comment: [You need to play with the coset](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/88209/18298)

Comment: This is something that is also of interest to me. Did you find any resources that list a secure way to achieve this conversion -- or whether this is sensible at all?

Comment: @cryptobeginner unfortunately, no.